# C# Importing and using custom dll via code

Tags: c#, compilation, dllimport

I'm trying to make an basic game editor for practise and I have my created my own GameEngine libary. I'm trying to create a new program and biring the GameEngine class into it. Here's my code.

GameEditor:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.dll", "System.Core.dll", "GameEngine.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

        string code =
        @"
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Text;
        using GameEngine;

        class Program {
          public static void Main(string[] args) {
                Game.Start();
            }

        }";

        CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
```

GameEngine.Game:

```
using System;

namespace GameEngine
{
    public class Game
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game engine has been started!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is foo.exe crashes everytime when I tried to use the Game.Start()

Comment: What is the error it gives when it crashes?

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/oYZq4o.png

Comment: Is the GameEngine.dll located next to the exe path of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. The only error I got at first was

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'GameEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
File name: 'GameEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This is my bad since I compiled `GameEngine` with .Net v4.5.But, when I compiled with 3.5 and moved the `GameEngine.dll` next to the `foo.exe` it worked and I got

```
...\bin\Debug>foo.exe
Game engine has been started!
```

If you're getting the error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'GameEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'GameEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Then the executable can't find the dll. Look for the dll yourself and see if has compiled and exists next to foo.exe

Comment: Thanks! I was forgot the changing the .net version of libary. Now It's working.